It is time to start another Sandbox (2024)
The current Sandbox has grown to the point where the browser experience is pretty slow. For example, the time needed to take you to the Sandbox after clicking a notification is pretty long. The nature of the beast is that it doesn't matter how well we keep it clean (although that helps a lot!) because deleted posts remain. Thus, we're at the time when it's become cumbersome to maintain the current Sandbox.
This is not the first time we've had to do this. In fact, this will be the fifth closure of the Sandbox.

The current Sandbox will be discontinued on December 31, 2024.
A new Sandbox will be set up on December 1, 2024.
Questions in the current Sandbox will be notified of the impending closure and the need to either wrap up efforts to craft questions or move the questions to the new Sandbox.
Any incomplete questions on January 1, 2025 will be arbitrarily deleted.

Question: The Sandbox must be hosted by a user. Previous hosts have been @ArtOfCode, @DaaaahWhoosh, @Bellerophon, @JBH and @JBH. Would someone else like to be the host?
I have found the experience rewarding, but technically, being the host can be nothing more than just a placeholder. It should be someone who will participate regularly in the Sandbox as a mentor. It must be someone willing to maintain the Sandbox. The host will be notified of every new question in the Sandbox. It's not a huge burden, but it is a commitment.
If you're interested in the job, please take the time to carefully read the Sandbox instructions via the link above, including the instructions for creating a new Sandbox. Don't do it yet, we need to wrap things up. Post an answer below letting us know that you'll do the job.
Thanks.

And let a moderator know when to make the old one obsolete...

@L.Dutch Yup, no problem.
